# Custom routing doesn't work correctly [F3]

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

The custom route doesn't work correctly and always routes to ***user.htm***

index.php

```
$routes = [
  "/" =>  "index.htm",
  "/user/id=@id" => "user.htm","/user/@id" => "user.htm",
];

foreach ($routes as $path => $file) {
  $f3->route("GET ".$path,
    function($f3){
      global $file,$path;
      echo View::instance()->render($file);
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$routes = [
  "/" => "index.htm",
  "/user/id=@id" => "user.htm",
  "/user/@id" => "user.htm",
];

foreach ($routes as $path => $file)
{
  $f3->route("GET " . $path,
    function ($f3) use ($file)
    {
      echo View::instance()->render($file);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Worked, thanks. But could you please elaborate why this works and the method i used doesn't? Thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Bryan Velastegui is the correct one. But here's why your code didn't work:

1. `$f3->route()` maps each route URI to a function (called the "route handler"), *without executing it*.
2. the `foreach` loop stores successively the following values into the `$file` variable: `index.html`, `user.htm` and `user.htm` (again). Therefore, at the end of the loop, `$file` holds `user.htm`.
3. once you call `$f3->run()`, the framework executes the route handler matching the current route, which itself refers to the global `$file` variable, holding `user.htm`.

Generally, you shouldn't be using the [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) keyword. That will just create unexpected issues, just as the one you've faced. Also that doesn't help for code maintainability.

I advise you to read the docs about the [use keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-160) to understand how Bryan Velastegui's code is working.

Comment: Thank you friend, I am really new and do not get very good explanations.